# Python match JSON value with regex

Tags: python, json, regex

I have a JSON like this in a list `agents_json`:

```
[
  {
    'name': 'ip-10-13-28-114 (5)',
    'active': True
  },
  {
    'name': 'ip-10-13-28-127 (6)',
    'active': True
  },
  {
    'name': 'ip-10-13-28-127',
    'active': True
  }
]
```

I want to delete the objects from the json where the value of the name matches my variable from a list: `agents_to_remove` it contains strings like the name value of the third object.

So Problem is my list doesn't contain the number between brackets and a lot of objects have names like that.

Can you tell me if its possible to match the json value with a regex in here:

```
for i in range(len(agents_json)):
    for j in agents_to_remove:
        regex = re.search(j*)
        if agents_json[i]["name"] == j* :
            agents_json.pop(i)
            break
```

Obviosly `j*` isn't working, and after a few hours of searching I still don't have any idea how I could accomplish this.

Comment: if that's only the brackets in the end that bother you, take a look at `str.startswith`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written looks like JSON - but if this is written in a python file it won't actually be a JSON object, like it might be in javascript, it will be a list of [dictionary objects](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp).

It sounds like to want to do some sort of regex or wild card matching to see if an agent in the list appears in the list of agents to be deleted. I don't know exactly what your data looks like but you might try:

```
remaining_agents = []
for agent in agents_json:
    if any(agent["name"].startswith(x) for x in agents_to_remove):
        continue
    else:
        remaining_agents.append(agent)

agents_json = remainig_agents
```

Comment: If you would like to find out more about regex's in python take a look at the examples here https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to [MindOfMetalAndWheels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61914613/1910637) solution, using a regular expression

```
import re

agents_json = [
    {
        'name': 'ip-10-13-28-114 (5)',
        'active': True
    },
    {
        'name': 'ip-10-13-28-127 (6)',
        'active': True
    },
    {
        'name': 'ip-10-13-28-127',
        'active': True
    }
]

agents_to_remove = ['ip-10-13-28-127']

# Iterate through a copy of the list:
for agent in agents_json[:]:
    for regex in agents_to_remove:
        if re.search(regex, agent["name"]):
            agents_json.remove(agent)
            break


print("checking ")

for a in agents_json:
    print(a["name"])
```